# put class in html if php condition meet

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I am using html navigation panel,
below is one of example of open tab.

```
<li class="nav-item active open">
```

Now, i want 'active open' to be applied when my url contains \testing\one.

I could get that url by using php code below, i am using codeigniter.

```
<?php echo $this->uri->uri_string();?>
```

I can compare it with if statement, but my main question is how can i put this php if condition in

```
<li></li>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way -

```
<li <?php echo ($this->uri->uri_string() === 'value') ? 'class="nav-item active open"' : '' ?>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="nav-item <?php if($this->uri->uri_string() === 'Value') { echo 'active open' } ?>" ></li>
```